# Slide up menu for Android, which can be swiped up

Tags: android

I would like to make a slide up menu for my app, similar to this:

[image: a slide up menu]

I would like to be able to hold the button and then slide the menu up with my finger.

I already did a slide up menu, which slides up when I click a button, but that is not really what I want. I also created one menu, that slides up when you swipe up on the display, but that didn't really worked, because of the map in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do it is using [BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior) or [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment)

[Here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/) you can find material guidelines and description for them

For your case you can create transparent layout (no matter what exactly, `LinearLayout` for example) with button inside layout and just set `peekHeight` attribute that equals button.

Comment: but with that I still can't swipe the menu up with a "button", can I?

Comment: @huhn3k updated post

Comment: thanks! just one more question... how can I make the button moveable to change it height?

Comment: @huhn3k just read guide like this one https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066